# Помогите написать программу, которая спрашивает у пользователя его имя и выводит в консоли текстовое поздравление

Tags: javascript

Помогите написать программу, которая спрашивает у пользователя его имя и выводит в консоли текстовое поздравление. Для этого нужно использовать цикл while или for.

Happy birthday to you

Happy birthday to you

Happy birthday, dear $NAME

Happy birthday to you

Создать 3 одинаковых строчки мне по силу, но как вставить между ними строчку с именем, не понимаю. Мой код:

```
let name = prompt('What is your name?');
let str = ''; 
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    str += 'Happy birthday to you \n';
}
console.log(str);
```

И да, сорри, я дно :(

Comment: и в чем сложность? где ваши попытки?

Comment: Вам нужна фриланс-площадка. SO - это сообщество, которое помогает разобраться в проблеме, а не решить её за кого-то.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let str = ''; 
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    if(i==3) str+='Happy birthday, dear $NAME\n'
    else str += 'Happy birthday to you \n';
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ был так прост...

Comment: Это ведь неверный ответ, в нем не вставляется в строку имя пользователя.

Comment: думаю как добавить переменную в строку разберутся, да и вопрос был не в том как добавить переменную в строку

Answer (score -1):

```
    function congratulate() {
        let userName = prompt('Введите ваше имя!');
        for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            let message = (i === 2) ? userName : 'you';
            console.log(`Happy birthday, dear ${message}!`);
        }
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]